# How to extract lines from log files based on an error keyword?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

This is a sample log file (below). When the keyword ORA-02063 exists in any line in the logs, I want to extract all  lines in the log file with that same timestamp.

I have tried to use grep, but that did not work since i could not extract the timestamp.

````
20200814 13:54:34 DEBUG (com.test.test.test.test2Servlet) [doPost]  Incoming XML request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webdoc>
</contract>
<notes>


some data

</notes>
    </contract>
</webdoc> 
20200814 13:54:34 ERROR (com.test.test.test.test2Servlet) [doPost] request failed: ccom.test.test.test.test2Servlet.exception.SystemFailureException: Database operation failed  - caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
ORA-02063: preceding stringstring from string```
````

Comment: for the log file snippet in the question the `ORA-02063` shows up on a line with no date/time stamp; is this correct (the error/number could show up on a line without a date/time stamp) or is this a typo and the `ORA-02063` should be part of the previous line?

Comment: @markp-fuso  it's not a typo, the lines are logged that way

Comment: `markp-fuso yeah, whatever` ... yep, whatever; cancelling answer; good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, not the best but a solution

```
grep "`grep 'ORA-02063' logfile -B1 | cut -d ' ' -f1,2 | head -n 1`" logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the example data in the file webdoc:

```
dayte=$(awk -v str="ORA-01461" '{ if (match($0,str)) { print substr($0,0,17) } }' webdoc)
```

Using awk, pass the string you want to search for, if it exists in the line, take the date and time stamp using the substr function and print. Read the result into a variable dayte.

With the variable dayte set, use sed to print the lines required:

```
sed -n '/'"$dayte"'/,/^<\/webdoc>/p' webdoc
```

Print all lines containing the date in question to the closing webdoc tag.

Note - Ensure that the dayte variable is quoted in the sed command.